# How to create a JSON feed

Tags: javascript, xml, json

I have a file called parsing.html that parses through a xml feed and converts the metadata into `JSON` Object called "data". I'm trying to output this `JSON` "data" as a JSON feed such as http://www.videws.com/gtv/videosources.php. Is doing
`document.write(JSON.stringify(data))` the equivalent of creating a `JSON` feed in this case?

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'fakeFeed.xml',
  dataType: 'xml',
  async: false,
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

  function getRandom(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
  }

  function getThumbId(small) {
    var num = getRandom(15);
    if (num == 0) {
      num = 1;
    }
    if (num < 10) {
      num = '0' + num;
    }
    return num.toString();
  }

  var categories = new Array();  // Array for the categories
  var category = {
    name : '',
    videos: []
  }; 
  var data1 = data;
  var data = {
    categories: []
  };

  $(data1).find('item').each(function () { 
    var el = $(this);
    var categoryName = el.find('category').text();
    var p = categories.indexOf(categoryName);
    if( p == -1) {
      categories.push(categoryName);
      var category = {
        name: categoryName,
        videos: []
      }; 
      for (var j = 0; j<5; j++) {
        var video = {
          sources: [el.find('media\\:content, content').attr('url')],
          thumb : 'images\/thumbs\/thumb' + getThumbId() + '.jpg',
          title : el.find("title").text(),
          subtitle : el.find("description").text(),
          description: ""            
        }
        //document.write(categories);
        category.videos.push(video);
      }
      data.categories.push(category);
    }
  });   
  document.write(JSON.stringify(data));
  } 
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im not sure you fully understand what http://www.videws.com/gtv/videosources.php is doing.

if you look at the source code it appears not to have any javascript at all so its not doing a document.write, it is more likely doing all of the conversion to JSON within PHP server side then streaming out.

a good help site for using PHP with JSON is available here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_php_example.htm

i would say that if your more of a JS/HTML guru you may get more out of NODEJS than PHP but that's entirely up to you.